# NSManagedObject methods are not getting called

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject

The `NSManagedObject` methods i.e. `awakeFromInsert`, `awakeFromFetch`, etc are not getting called, when implemented in the `NSManagedObject` subclass. What could be the reason? The Entity "Class" is set to subclass in the Entity model editor.

**Event.m**

```
#import "Event.h"

@implementation Event

@dynamic timeStamp;

- (void)awakeFromInsert {
    NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);
    [super awakeFromInsert];
}

- (void)awakeFromFetch {
    NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);
    [super awakeFromFetch];
}

@end
```

**MyViewController (Insert)**

```
- (void)insertNewObject:(id)sender {
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self.fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [[self.fetchedResultsController fetchRequest] entity];
    NSManagedObject *newManagedObject = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:[entity name] inManagedObjectContext:context];

    [newManagedObject setValue:[NSDate date] forKey:@"timeStamp"];

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![context save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }
}
```

And here's a screen-shot of the model editor. [image]

Note: I'm using Xcode 4.4.1 (iOS SDK 5.1) on Mountain Lion, with ARC ON.

Comment: Share some code about your subclasses. Thanks.

Comment: Need to see the code where you create instance of `Event` and other related information to help you figure out the problem.

Comment: Question edited to include the information. The code is basically all from the Master Detail project template.

Comment: Perhaps `Event.m` is not added to your target? I have tested your `awakeXXX` methods with the Master Detail project template and it worked without problems.

Comment: Can you cast `Event` to your `*newManagedObject` and see what happens? i.e. Event *newManagedObject = [NSEntityDescription insert...]`.

Comment: Can you show where you instantiate your `NSNFetchedResultsController`'s `fetchRequest`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

make sure your classes are added to the targets, and also make sure they're specified in the model. If you don't specify the subclass within the model, per entity, it won't matter that you have the classes included in the target; you'll just be dealing with an NSManagedObject.

Comment: and yes, saw that you have that set properly; just including the detail in case somebody else ever comes across this with a similar problem

Comment: Bingo! Yeah, for some reason, the Event.m class was not added to the target... I wonder why. Anyways, thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: you're most welcome. I have gotten tripped up by the other possibility before; forgetting to specify the subclass in the model and then wondering why on earth none of my custom stuff is in play. Little things that can drive you mad...;-)

Comment: For anyone else who finds this, don't forget to do Product->Clean after changing the model.

Comment: VERY WISE words... Thank you so much! Was so perplexed why it didn't work suddenly when I changed another entity.